# asp.net mvc code first set database version

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using the aps.net mvc 4 code first entity framework.

If there's no database, my application creates the databases as it should. 
The problem is, that they are generated in the version 706 (Sql Server 2012) but I need it as an older version, so I can run/handle it with Sql Server 2008

Is there a way to configure in which version the database is generated?

Answer (score 1):

If I can remember now I think the attribute you are looking for is ProviderManifestToken.

Have a look at [this](http://forums.oreilly.com/topic/3970-chapter-20-sample/) article for how to change it.